# How does one efficiently implement file region locking using grand central dispatch?

Tags: parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch, file-locking

For my project, I am reading from and writing to a file from multiple threads, so I need to implement file locking. I have tried `fcntl()`, however it seems that function only works with locking between processes, not between threads. As such, I am looking for another solution. The solution which I came up with (which is probably not the best) is to have a byte in each record in my file to indicate whether the record is locked, and I could then use a busy loop to read and check the byte.

So, I have two questions. First, what is the most efficient way to implement file region locking? Second, if I go with the busy loop approach, how can I optimize that with grand central dispatch? I was thinking that I could make all of the busy loops occur in blocks sent to `dispatch_sync()`. But I don't know whether or not that would even work efficiently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Dispatch Semaphore](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_semaphore_create.3.html)? You can use Dispatch Semaphore to access exclusively resources. For instance, create Dispatch Semaphores for your file regions.

```
for (int i = 0; i < regions; ++i)
    sema_[i] = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
```

And then, access resources with wait and signal.

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema_[region], DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
/* access the region */
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema_[region]);
```

Comment: The issue with that is that then I have to allocate memory for each region. Once it gets to be a large file, that is a lot of memory (as each record in the file would need allocated memory). I could use a map of record ids to semaphores. However, I would need a single semaphore to lock that map, or implement an atomic linked list which would cause a bottleneck.

Comment: mmap might resolve large file problem. Or you might want database library like libsqlite3. It provides thread-safe access for a large file.